# How multiple type lists are stored in memory?

Tags: memory, array, list

Arrays are stored in a linear fashion, with memory cells of fixed size for each element. To have fixed sized memory cells Arrays should be homogenious. So in Arrays we get an Nth element by skipping certain amount of bits (defined by element type) N times.

But what about lists? Or heterogenious arrays like we have in JavaScript? How are they stored in memory. And how does accessing a certain element work with lists?

Comment: Your question is unclear: are you asking about (linked) lists, heterogenous arrays, or JavaScript arrays? And if you are asking about JavaScript arrays, which of the dozens of implementations are you asking about?

Answer (score 2):

> How are they stored in memory.

In general, this is not something which is defined by a language specification. A specific *implementation* of a language is free to store something in memory however it likes so long as that implementation is consistent with the behaviour defined by the language specification.

That said, the answer for JavaScript is mostly "everything is a reference" - the object itself is not stored in the array or list, but a pointer to the actual object, and that pointer is of constant size independent of the type of object it is pointing to.

For the other end of the scale, look at something like C: there, arrays do contain the object directly, and can therefore only contain objects of one specific type.

Comment: let's say I have a heterogenious array in JavaScript `const arr = [21, "summer", true, null]`. The array itself is an object. But how are the elements of the array are stored in the memory? They all are primitive but have different sizes since they are of different types.

Comment: They will likely be [boxed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_(computer_science)). But again, _implementation dependent_.

Comment: There’s the “Any” protocol in Swift which can be _anything_.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I did not look up JavaScript's implementation*

For your example of `const arr = [21, "summer", true, null]` my **guess**, as Philip Kendall also pointed out, is that it's likely stored in memory as references to your data.

If it stores each piece of your data in memory at it's own location:

```
memory location a -> (Integer) 21
memory location b -> (String) "summer"
memory location c -> (Boolean) true
memory location d -> (Object) null
```

then your array can just hold consistent length references that point to each piece of data:

```
memory location e -> (Array) [reference a, reference b, reference c, reference d]
```

Comment: You might also have a tagged-pointer optimization to store small immediate values like null, undefined, booleans, and small integers directly inline without needing heap allocation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer

Answer (score -1):

In languages with arrays supporting multiple types of elements usually what is stored is pointers, object references and so on, which all have the same size, so the problem goes away.

“Lists” are implemented any way the implementation likes. I’d probably use an array or a list of arrays as the underlying structure because I don’t like lots of little allocations.